# How to calculate difference between current date and previous date in different rows

Tags: sql, date, teradata-sql-assistant

Hi I want to calculate the difference between dates in different rows using sql teradata assistant

my table look like this

```
create table test (
    id INT,
    Dx varchar(10)
    Dx_date date);

    insert into TEST values(1,'E14','2015-05-03');
insert into TEST values(1,'E15','2013-05-06');
insert into TEST values(1,'E15','2016-03-03');
insert into TEST values(2,'E15','2012-03-04');
insert into TEST values (3,'E144','2011-03-04');
insert into TEST values  (3,'E122','2011-02-04');
```

Than to calculate the difference of dates between each row I'm using this code

```
select id,
            dx, 
            Date_dx, 
            zeroifnull (MDIFF(Date_dx,1,id,dx)
            from TEST
            group by id;
```

But it gaves me wrong results

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

> A window function should make this easy.

For date difference in **days**:

```
  Select *
 ,DateDiff(DD, Dx_date, Lag(Dx_Date) Over (Order By Dx_date)) DateDiff
 From test
```

Although you did not specify, your attempt to calculate the date, suggests you many be interested in calculating dates per id, so;

```
Select  *
        ,DateDiff(DD, Dx_date, Lag(Dx_Date) Over (Partition by id Order By Dx_date)) DateDiff
From test
```

**Note:** you may need to edit the date function as appropriate.

Comment: The code dosen't work I'am guetting an error message "data type "Dx_date" does not match a Defined type name"

Comment: Please refer to the **"Note"** in my answer .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select id, dx, datediff(day, lastdate, date_dx) datedifference from (
    select id,
                dx, 
                Date_dx, 
                lag(Date_dx,1,null) over(order by id)lastdate
                from TEST)A
```

Comment: The code dosen't work neither I think the datediff and lag functions don't exist in Teradata Sql –

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
select id ,dx,Dx_date,
       zeroifnull(dx_date-min(dx_date) over (partition by id order by dx_date rows 
       between 1 preceding and 1 preceding )) as difference _dx_date
from TEST;
```

Thank you